# Navigating XAML page using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am doing Windows Store App and it has 3 pages.

1. main page
2. page 1
3. page 2

main page is called in App.xaml.cpp

```
 void App::OnLaunched(Windows::ApplicationModel::Activation::
                      LaunchActivatedEventArgs^ args)
 {

 }
```

I have button in main page called "Next" and on the click event of this button i wanted to go to next page  i.e page 1 and than so on.
I am using this

```
                this->Frame->Navigate(__typeof(Page1));
```

But I getting compile time error as follows

error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Frame'
  Page1 : illegal use of this type as an expression

I have added

```
using namespace Platform;    
using namespace Windows::Foundation;    
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Data;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Input;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Navigation;    
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Interop;
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution we have to use it in this way

this->Frame->Navigate(TypeName(NameCamera::typeid));

Comment: The `TypeName(...)` is superfluous:  `this->Frame->Navigate(NameCamera::typeid);` should work fine (`T::typeid` yields a `Platform::Type^`, which is implicitly convertible to a `Platform::TypeName`.)